# what does `wad`stand for

Tags: solidity, tokens, dapple

in many token contracts the amount parameter is called `wad`

I was not able to make sense what this means or where it comes from. Does someone have a clue?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As i know it was introduced by Dapp [tool-suite](https://dapp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (part of dapphub project) as a concept representing a number with 18 decimals. 
So i presume the contract developed using Dapp libraries or tools use the same names.

Comment: thank you. I have not marked your answer as accepted because it does not clarify the meaning of the acronym (I assume it is an acronym) wad

Comment: It is not an acronym . Google defines it as bundle of paper, banknotes, or documents.
"a thick wad of index cards"

Answer (score 17):

A `wad` is a decimal number with 18 digits of precision that is being represented as an integer.

A `ray` is a decimal number with 27 digits of precision that is being represented as an integer.

Under the hood, they both are `uint` (i.e. `uint256`).

Introduced by [DS-Math](https://github.com/dapphub/ds-math) library. With DS-Math you can safely add, subtract, multiply, and divide uint numbers without fear of integer overflow. You can also find the minimum and maximum of two numbers.

This naming convention helps a programmer avoid mistakes while performing arithmetic operations on these values.

Hope this helps!